# Is it possible to run an Adobe AIR app without installation?

Tags: air, adobe

Is it possible to run an Adobe AIR app without installing it? The AIR runtime is already installed, and we need a solution to control the 'installation' of applications - so what we need is run an adobe air app which just runs and doesn't presents the installer when launched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. Adobe call it a captive runtime, and I believe this is only supported under Adobe Air 3.0 and up.

Their website does a good job of explaining various pros and cons at [Packaging a captive runtime bundle for desktop computers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html)

Comment: Thanks, captive runtime is a solution for this and I'll accept your answer. Although we did some experimenting and found another solution which works with existing apps we don't own (we cannot package them).

The thing is: if you install an Adobe AIR app with a standard .air distribution / installer it will produce OS dependent executable from the app. On Windows by default it's in C:/Program Files on Mac it's the Applications folder. You can copy this installed version and transfer to another machine and if AIR is installed on the target machine it will work correctly.

Comment: Does the captive runtime solution require the computer where you want to run it to have Air installed?